# mod rewrite an URL like "http://miniqr.com/http://www.anyurl.com/" (no typo)

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-shortener

ok, basically

> http://miniqr.com/http://www.anyurl.com/

(no typo)

should call

> http://miniqr.com/api/create.php?content=http://www.anyurl.com/

to achieve this i have this in the root .htaccess

> RewriteRule ^http:\/\/(.*)$
>   \/api\/create.php\?content=http:\/\/$1
>   [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^https:\/\/(.*)$
>   \/api\/create.php\?content=https:\/\/$1
>   [L]

sad thing is, it once worked, then the server was updated, now it doesn't work

anybody knows why? (or know another way to do it) help would be awesome

my .htaccess pretty much looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^miniqr\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://miniqr.com/$1  [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(^$|index\.php|robots\.txt|docs|reader\/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^http:\/\/(.*)$ \/api\/create\.php\?content=http:\/\/$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^https:\/\/(.*)$ \/api\/create\.php\?content=https:\/\/$1  [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL path is normalized before `RewriteRule` sees it, in particular, `//` is replaced by `/`. You should apply your rule to the original request instead like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(https?:.*)
RewriteRule ^ /api/create.php?content=%1 [L]
```

`%1` refers to the match done by `RewriteCond`.
`%{REQUEST_URI}` is the actual query in the first line of the HTTP request.

---

Alternatively, be less strict and accept a single `/` after the scheme as well as `//`, since the path might be similarly normalized by the user agent or by proxies.

Comment: tried the first approach, worked perfectly, will see about the other. thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Don't this introduce a redirection loop?:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^miniqr\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://miniqr.com/$1  [L,R=301]
```

What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: http://www.miniqr.com/.* -> HTTP 301  -> http://miniqr.com/.* and it seems to work

Comment: the comment CMS screwed up the comment above ... www.miniqr.com -> HTTP 301  -> miniqr.com